# when I use bitset in unoder container,what the hash function look like?

Tags: c++, c++14

It is said that in the book of Nicolai Josuttis, The C++ Standard Library, the default hash function is provided. And, what the default function mean? Provided by the user or by the C++ standard?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00759_source.html#l01498

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function **has** to be provided by the implementation of Standard library you are using. C++ standard does not provide the function.

Comment: what the function look like? Lexicographic compare?

Comment: @TuXiaomi If you really want to know, you can consult the documentaion (or source code, it's likely a header-only template) of your standard library. But for most purposes, you shouldn't care.

Comment: @TuXiaomi, just look in the source code of the library. However, you can be certain about one thing - it **will not* be a lexicographic compare.